# How do you get the results of a SQL Server stored procedure in JSON?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I want to execute an existing stored procedure in SQL Server and get the results out in JSON.

Details: existing stored procedure `dbo.pr_GetUser` returns a recordset.

I want to create a wrapper that will do the following:

```
EXEC dbo.pr_GetUser 
FOR JSON AUTO
```

This will allow me to consume an existing stored procedure and not be concerned about the inner workings or modifications in logic.

Is this possible without editing the existing stored procedure?

Comment: I know it's not recommended to ask questions in the comments, but did you end up figuring something out?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this,

```
INSERT INTO #table(userId int)
EXEC dbo.pr_GetUser

select userId  from #table FOR JSON Auto
```

Note that table structure of #table will be same as the result.

Comment: The challenge would be that the Wrapper would break when the stored procedure returns more columns. The Developer of the original stored procedure may not know who is consuming the stored procedure, but the signature of the procedure will remain the same for backwards compatibility.

Comment: do u mean, result will not be same structure ?

Comment: The original columns and data types that are returned, will always remain the same and will not be removed or modified, but additional columns may be returned in the future which I don't necessarily need to use.